# PHP MySql fetch json no content

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have problem fetching my result from a database and convert to JSON. In my API call, It gives me empty content (total blank) of returned body with status 200.

This is my code:

```
$weekAndYear = $year."/".$week; // incoming params as e.g "2016/19"

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT r.*, p.code FROM report r, product p WHERE "
        . "r.pid=p.pid AND r.product=:productCode "
        . "AND r.status='Published' AND r.pid=25 AND r.week=:weekAndYear");
$stmt->bindparam(":productCode", $productCode);
$stmt->bindparam(":weekAndYear", $weekAndYear);
$stmt->execute();

while($price=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //echo $price;
    $arr_price[] = $price;
 }
 

$data['priceReport'] = $arr_price;
 
 
//echo $weekAndYear;
$data['status'] = "OK";

return json_encode($data);
```

When I tested the query in my phpmyadmin MySQL server and it works fine.

On my PHP side, different `$weekAndYear` params will have some working well and some are not. Anything wrong on array part?

My API response headers:

> Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
> check=0
> Connection →Keep-Alive
> Content-Length →0
> Content-Type →application/json
> Date →Thu, 05 May 2016 06:49:28 GMT
> Expires →Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
> Pragma →no-cache
> Server →Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) LibreSSL/2.2.6 PHP/5.5.31
> X-Powered-By →PHP/5.5.31

Please help.

Comment: did you try logging the $data variable to see if it's empty?

Comment: As your not using any function so write echo json_encode($data);

Comment: This is written in php class that's why I use return, but in my another function, return and echo works well. On the $weekAndYear param,  when I changed to 2016/18 it works, but when I typed 2019/19 it didn't, 2016/17 it works,... some are working fine but some are not. But for all of these, the queries work fine on the phpmyadmin side.

Comment: While having my last hair standing, I've found out that there's a string value in one of the column in table contains special characters: ºÚ×Ö, which cause the strange behavior of my returned API response. Well I have overcome this by only selecting the columns I wish to grab from table. Hoever will post an answer on how to solve this issue. Something like array_map('utf8_encode', $arr)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (maybe wrongly) that your code snippet isn't a function.
Change the last line from return to echo as follows:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I've tested it but it won't solve the problem. echo and return do the same trick and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the first code snippet is a function, you need to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) not a return statement.

What happens is that Fetch can fetch any type of content, even HTML. What PHP does is it generates content writes it to a file and sends it to the browser. When you generate HTML with PHP you do not return it, you `echo` it to the page.

The same thing happens with AJAX. You use PHP to write data to a file and serve it.

So replace this:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

with this:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```